# Code returns "none" on codecademy and im not sure why

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

Instructions:

> First, def a function called distance_from_zero, with one argument (choose any >argument name you like).
>
> If the type of the argument is either int or float, the function should return >the absolute value of the function input.
>
> Otherwise, the function should return "Nope"

I've done the first task and I *thought* that i completed the task, however

"Your function seems to fail on input True when it returned 'None' instead of 'Nope'"

Here is my code:

```
def distance_from_zero(argument):
if type(argument) == int or type(argument) == float:
    return abs(argument)
    print(argument)
else:
    print("Nope")
```

From what ive seen in other modules codecademy tests this with my arguement being "1", such that the if statement goes through, will return the absolute value of (argument) and then i would pass the module. (i added print(argument) for testing purposes, the console outputs nothing.)

Am i mis understanding how returning works? Why is this not working?
I appreciate all responses! :)

EDIT: It prints "None", not "Nope" in the console. Forgot to mention this.

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement in the `else` clause. Your function _prints_ the string `'Nope'` instead of _returning_ it.

Comment: The function prints nothing, "None", not "Nope", sorry if i wasnt clear

Comment: printing is not the same as returning.

Comment: I think i will have to look over returning, im quite confused by it haha. Either way i returned in the else statement and i passed, thanks :^)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if return isn't explicit, it becomes `None`. Try this:

```
def distance_from_zero(argument):
    if type(argument) == int or type(argument) == float:
        print(abs(argument))
    else:
        print("Nope")

> f = distance_from_zero(-4234)
4234
> f
None
```

As you can see the *value* of f is `None`, this is because `print` is outputting to the console and not actively returning content. Instead, try using the `return` statement:

```
def distance_from_zero(argument):
    if type(argument) == int or type(argument) == float:
        return abs(argument)
    else:
        return "Nope"

> distance_from_zero(123)
123 
# here, because you're not assigning the value returned to a variable, it's just output.
> f = distance_from_zero(-4234)
> f
4234
> f = distance_from_zero('cat')
> f
'Nope'
```

It's also important to know that the reason this:

```
return abs(argument)
print(argument)
```

printed to the console is *not* because of the `print` call. Anything after `return` in a block is not executed. The reason you see the output printed to the screen is because in the interpreter Python outputs all function return values not collected into variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance_from_zero(num):
    if type(num) == int or type(num) == float:
        return abs(num)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

Comment: def distance_from_zero(num):
  if type(num) == int or type(num) == float:
    return abs(num)
  else:
    return "Nope"